# procedure entry point setdefaultdlldirectories could not be located kernel32.dll

Tags: windows-7, atom-editor

I want to install latest version of Atom (code editor) to my win-7 32 bit computer. But I face this problem:

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: harry's answer also worked on a similar error on my dell laptop `Entry Point Not Found. The procedure entry point AddDllDirectory could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll`  failing that one would have to install all "important" updates!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows 7 you need to download and install update KB2533623 from
this [Microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533623/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remot).

This update is described as:

> Microsoft has released new API enhancements for Windows to help
> developers correctly and securely load external libraries. For more
> information, visit the following Microsoft webpages:
>
> - SetDefaultDllDirectories
> - AddDllDirectory
> - RemoveDllDirectory

**Edit:** The download has disappeared from the above link, but is still
available from the
[Microsoft Update Catalog : KB2533623](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2533623).

**Edit 2:** Microsoft updated Windows 7 KB2533623 fix with some additional other security patches too. Because of that the KB number changed and old patch removed from server. New package name is KB4457144. The package can be found in
[Microsoft Update Catalog : KB4457144](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4457144)

Comment: Yes, after installation it works well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This solved my Slack 64bit installation issue.

Comment: @MitulMarsoniya: I had no difficulties with the link - might have been a momentary glitch. Just remember that this is about Windows 7.

Comment: @harrymc Just go to link then after try to (Update for Windows 7 (KB2533623) download software. You can't download.

Comment: @MitulMarsoniya: You're right, the download has disappeared. But it is still available from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2533623).